# Why am I getting an infinite loop

Tags: java, file

I have just made a program that is supposed to scan a file and count the number of lines, vowels, and many other things but when I run it, it goes into an infinite loop. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the `.hasNext()` and `.hasNextLine()`  methods which I am not very familiar with

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 *
 *
 */
public class Wordcount1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int vowels=0;
        int punctuation=0;
        int sentences=0;
        int words=0;
        int lines=0;
        int alphaNumeric=0;

       try{
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter file name: ");

       File file = new File(input.nextLine());
       Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);

       while(fileReader.hasNextLine()){
           lines +=1;
       }
       while(fileReader.hasNext()){
           { fileReader.next();
           words +=1;
           }
           String word = fileReader.next();
           for (int i=0; i<word.length();i++){
               char ch= word.charAt(i);
               if(ch=='a'||ch=='e'||ch=='i'||ch=='o'||ch=='u')
                   vowels +=1;
               if((ch=='!'||ch=='.'||ch=='?'))
                   sentences +=1;
               if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch))
                   alphaNumeric +=1;
               switch(ch){
                   case ',':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case '[':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case ']':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case ':':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case '`':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case '-':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case '!':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case '_': 
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case '(':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case ')':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case '.':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case '?':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case '"':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;
                   case ';':
                    punctuation +=1;
                    break;

               }

           }
       }
        System.out.println("The number of words in the file name: " + words);
        System.out.println("The number of lines in the file name: " + lines);
        System.out.println("The number of alphanumeric characters: "
                + "in the file name: " + alphaNumeric);
        System.out.println("The number of sentences in the file name: "
                + sentences);
        System.out.println("The number of vowels in the file name: " + vowels);
        System.out.println("The number of punctuations in the file name: " 
                + punctuation);

       }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first cycle to count the lines you never read actually read anything and the pointer to the file remains in the same place.

Comment: You program needs a lot of work (too much to cover), but you might consider this small cleanup: replace `words +=1` with `words++` (etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(fileReader.hasNextLine()){
    lines +=1;
}
```

Here, you're repeatedly asking the file "do you have any more lines", but never actually consuming any lines. So, it keeps answering "yes, I have more lines".

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not invoking `next()` method on fileReader

Invoking [Scanner.hasNext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) only says if it has a token or not, but doesn't advance the scanner: